# how to hide an array type of entity in a form in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an array type in an entity I want to add it to form type as a hidden field. I tried the following but it doesnt work. It just kills the browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
//Entity
    class Test{

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="test_image_files", type="array",nullable=true)
         */
        private $testImages; 

         /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getTestImages()
        {
            return $this->testImages;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $testImages
         */
        public function setTestImages($testImages)
        {
            $this->testImages = $testImages;
        }

    }
```

// FormType

```
class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('testImages','hidden');
    }
}
```

//twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.testImages) }}
```

Comment: Do you even need that field?

Comment: have you tried serializing the array before putting it in a form?, or converting it to text. i believe form fields are pretty basic, they can handle text and numbers (and files), i haven't tried with more 'complex objects' as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to handle current situation,

Echo `form_widget(form.testImages)` inside `<div style="display:none"></div>`.

I hope this helps.